# Change default namespace to named namespace using XSLT

Tags: xml, namespaces, xslt-1.0

my application current produces an XML file that uses a default namespace. Unfortunately the receiving system requires a prefix for the same namespace.

This easiest way for me to fix this is to apply an XSLT script. The challenge is (for me) to write that script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xbrl xml:lang="nl" 
      xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:kvk-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/kvk/tuples/kvk-tuples" 
      xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
      xmlns:nl-cd="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/sbr/items/nl-common-data" 
      xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi">
      <link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/report/kvk/entrypoints/algemeen/kvk-rpt-kleine-rechtspersoon-publicatiestukken-2014.xsd" />
      <context id="D-2014">
         <entity>
            <identifier scheme="http://www.kvk.nl/kvk-id">010101</identifier>
         </entity>
         <period>
            <startDate>2014-01-01</startDate>
            <endDate>2014-12-31</endDate>
         </period>
      </context>
      <unit id="u-EUR">
         <measure>iso4217:EUR</measure>
      </unit>
      <unit id="u-pure">
         <measure>pure</measure>
      </unit>
      <nl-cd:StatutoryNameEntity contextRef="D-2014">Company Name</nl-cd:StatutoryNameEntity>  
 </xbrl>
```

The required xml would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xml:lang="nl" 

      xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"

      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:kvk-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/kvk/tuples/kvk-tuples" 
      xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
      xmlns:nl-cd="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/sbr/items/nl-common-data" 
      xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi">
      <link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/report/kvk/entrypoints/algemeen/kvk-rpt-kleine-rechtspersoon-publicatiestukken-2014.xsd" />
      <xbrli:context id="D-2014">
         <xbrli:entity>
            <xbrli:identifier scheme="http://www.kvk.nl/kvk-id">010101</xbrli:identifier>
         </xbrli:entity>
         <xbrli:period>
            <xbrli:startDate>2014-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
            <xbrli:endDate>2014-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
         </xbrli:period>
      </xbrli:context>
      <xbrli:unit id="u-EUR">
         <xbrli:measure>iso4217:EUR</xbrli:measure>
      </xbrli:unit>
      <xbrli:unit id="u-pure">
         <xbrli:measure>pure</xbrli:measure>
      </xbrli:unit>
      <nl-cd:StatutoryNameEntity contextRef="D-2014">Company Name</nl-cd:StatutoryNameEntity>  
 </xbrli:xbrl>
```

Looking at a lot of answers on XML and namespaces I have been able to produce a script that does most of the job.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
            xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:kvk-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/kvk/tuples/kvk-tuples" xmlns:nl-cd="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/sbr/items/nl-common-data" 
            xmlns:rj-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/rj/items/rj-data" xmlns:venj-bw2-dm="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/venj/domains/venj-bw2-domains" 
            xmlns:venj-bw2-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/venj/tuples/venj-bw2-tuples" xmlns:rj-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/rj/tuples/rj-tuples" 
            xmlns:kvk-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/kvk/items/kvk-data" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" 
            xmlns:venj-bw2-dim="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/venj/axes/venj-bw2-axes" xmlns:venj-bw2-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/venj/items/venj-bw2-data" 
            xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi"  >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xbrli:xbrl"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xbrli:xbrl" >
    <xbrli:xbrl>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>           
    </xbrli:xbrl>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xbrli:context" >
    <xbrli:context>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>           
    </xbrli:context>
</xsl:template>

<!-- more template like this for the other elements like period, startdate, enddate -->
```

This procedures a good enough output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xbrli:xbrl xml:lang="nl" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:kvk-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/kvk/tuples/kvk-tuples" xmlns:nl-cd="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/sbr/items/nl-common-data" xmlns:rj-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/rj/items/rj-data" xmlns:venj-bw2-dm="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/venj/domains/venj-bw2-domains" xmlns:venj-bw2-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/venj/tuples/venj-bw2-tuples" xmlns:rj-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/rj/tuples/rj-tuples" xmlns:kvk-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/kvk/items/kvk-data" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:venj-bw2-dim="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/venj/axes/venj-bw2-axes" xmlns:venj-bw2-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/venj/items/venj-bw2-data" xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi">
<link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple"
  xlink:href="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/report/kvk/entrypoints/algemeen/kvk-rpt-kleine-rechtspersoon-publicatiestukken-2014.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" />
<xbrli:context id="D-2014">
  <xbrli:entity>
    <xbrli:identifier scheme="http://www.kvk.nl/kvk-id">34146188</xbrli:identifier>
</xbrli:entity>
<xbrli:period>
  <xbrli:startDate>2014-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
  <xbrli:endDate>2014-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
</xbrli:period>
```

The remaining problem is that each line now has the original default namespace mentioned:

```
<nl-cd:StatutoryNameEntity contextRef="D-2014" 
 xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance">Company name</nl-cd:StatutoryNameEntity>
```

Any suggestions how to get right of those namespaces?

Thanks.

Comment: You elements are already in the `http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance` namespace they are just not bound to the `xbrli` namespace-prefix. Semantically there is no difference between the document you have and the one you want to have. Namespace prefixes are only a convenience (or a requirement when used with attributes) but should never rely on them when processing an Xml document programmatically. It would be good to understand why you want to change the representation where there is no semantic difference between what you have and what you think you need.

Comment: "*This easiest way for me to fix this is to apply an XSLT script.*" Perhaps, but the **right** way to fix this is to go where the real problem is - and that is the non-conforming target application.

Comment: I agree completely that this change makes no semantical sense. It is a requirement from a governmental organisation. Getting this changed is not possible on the short term.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wity your stylesheet is the use of `xsl:copy`:

> Instantiating the `xsl:copy` element creates a copy of the current node.
>   **The namespace nodes of the current node are automatically copied as 
>   well**, but the attributes and children of the node are 
>   not automatically copied.

(emphasis added, source: [XSL specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying))

Instead of using `xsl:copy` you can use `xsl:element` which allows to specify the desired prefix.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
    xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:kvk-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/kvk/tuples/kvk-tuples" 
    xmlns:nl-cd="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/sbr/items/nl-common-data" 
    xmlns:rj-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/rj/items/rj-data" 
    xmlns:venj-bw2-dm="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/venj/domains/venj-bw2-domains" 
    xmlns:venj-bw2-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/venj/tuples/venj-bw2-tuples" xmlns:rj-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/rj/tuples/rj-tuples" 
    xmlns:kvk-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/kvk/items/kvk-data" 
    xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" 
    xmlns:venj-bw2-dim="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/domein/venj/axes/venj-bw2-axes" 
    xmlns:venj-bw2-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/9.0/basis/venj/items/venj-bw2-data" 
    xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | text()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xbrli:*" >
        <xsl:element name="xbrli:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>           
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- the elements in the `http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance` namespace are explicitly given the `xbrli` prefix, and the XSLT processor *will probably* use it (I tested with saxon, and it works); note that, as the `xbrli` prefix is already bound to the desired namespace in the stylesheet, there is no need to explicitly use the `namespace` attribute (many thanks to [michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k) for pointing this out)

> XSLT processors **may** make use of the prefix of the QName specified in
>   the `name` attribute when selecting the prefix used for outputting the
>   created element as XML; however, they are not required to do so.

(emphasis added, source: [XSL specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-element))

- other elements keep their current prefix (and namespace)
- attributes and text nodes can be copied with `xsl:copy`

A final note: I think it's really strange for an application to require a specific **prefix** (I'm not doubting what you say, I question the correctness of the application); the [XML Namespace specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#ns-qualnames) states:

> Note that the prefix functions only as a placeholder for a namespace
>   name. Applications SHOULD use the namespace name, not the prefix, in
>   constructing names whose scope extends beyond the containing document.

Comment: IMHO, your last template alone, together with the standard identity transform template (yes, using copy) would do the same job. Also, `<xsl:element name="xbrli:{local-name()}"> already places the element in the namespace bound to the prefix - so it's not redundant to do it again  explicitly by using the namespace attribute

Comment: @michael.hor257k: with the standard identity template, the elements not in the `xbrli` namespace are given **all** the namespaces declared in the input document, not just the needed ones (tested with saxon 6.5.5 for xslt 1, and saxon he 9.6.0 for xslt 2); thanks for your other observation, I'm going to update the answer.